# Can I turn a testnet node off every night?

Tags: nodes, goerli

I'm interested in running a EL+CL node on a testnet to aid development. Can I turn it off overnight?

I assume it de-registers itself gracefully from the network so I'm guessing the problem will be synching on each boot. I have CAT6 and ~132Mbit broadband. It'll need to catch-up usually 12h of blocks.

I just need a ballpark; to find peers and catch up a day's testnet activity, is it 20 minutes or 2 hours on each restart?

Optional bonus question: what about a mainnet node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can turn a node off overnight.

As long as you gracefully shut it down (can take a few minutes). A forced shutdown can damage the database if a recent state was being written to the disk. That would require you to resync the entire database.

If you are just catching up for the Goerli testnet I would expect this to be less than 15min for 12 hrs.

The mainnet handles 15-20x more transactions per day and you thus this process could take 15-20x longer. Turning off the main net would hurt your staking and is not advised.

Hope that gives you some idea what to expect.

Answer (score 2):

My computer can catch up to BSC mainnet at about 3-4 times realtime (about 3-4 hours caught up for every hour running). BSC is about a zillion times more demanding than any Ethereum testnet could hope to be, so you should have no problem.